# Non-sensical talk from a drunk man

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking

Uncle John drinks a lot. Yesterday when he was drunk he saw something and told me:

> A man put some threads in water and after his subsequent actions,  residents of the house were captured and the funny thing is the house ran out of the window in almost no time.

Is Uncle John talking non-sense, or he really saw something normal that fits to what he said?

Comment: Could this be chess related?

Comment: @BrentHackers It would be throwing away a hint, but no, it is not related to chess.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Did uncle john see a fish tank being cleaned?  Some fish (the residents) were captured/netted (by the thread) in a fish tank (the window) from which the water (their house?) ran.

Alternatively:

> A man could have been fishing in a lock.  He "captured" fish (the residents) with threads (fishing line) and then the lock was opened and the water (the house) ran out through the window (the lock gate).

Comment: I would say you are in right direction. Formulating this a little more can make this sound even better.

Comment: Does that last change get me any closer or do I need to think outside the box a little more?

Comment: A lot clearer than before.

Comment: can you explain why it is funny that the water ran out in no time?

Comment: @Ben I thought it may only be 'funny' in the context of drunken ramblings, as in referring to 'water pouring from a tank' as 'a house running out of a window'.

Answer (score 4):

Threads in water:

> Someone was making spaghetti

House:

> Cooking pot with water

Capturing residents:

> Taking cooked spaghetti out of the water

House running out of the window:

> pouring the water out of the pot

To sum it up:

> A man put spaghetti in water and after he cooked them, he took them out and it was funny (?) how quickly he poured the water out of the pot

Answer (score 4):

> Uncle John saw a man put a fishing net in water for fishing, residents of the house i.e fishes were caught and the water(house) drained out of the net (window is the gap in the net) in no time.

Comment: This is the situation I had in mind while I made the puzzle. Brent Hackers got it more than 99.9% right before so I can't accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Uncle John saw a raid in an illegal brewery in a casino during the prohibition.

A man put some threads in water

> Some hop or other herbs

residents of the house were captured

> A raid of the police

the house ran out of the window in almost no time.

> The casino owners fled

Answer (score 0):

Lets try:

> Uncle John saw a cat getting washed to remove the lice (residents) from its pels (the threads and the house).
>  And because a cat doesn't like water it ran out of the window after its owner let it go.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good attempt. But let me tell, there is much more plausible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense to me

> A man put some clothing in a fishbowl and after his subsequent actions, fish were caught in the clothes and the funny thing is the water in the fishbowl was displaced by the clothes and spilled over the bowl's opening in almost no time.

Answer (score -1):

improving @BrentHackers answer; is it

> some animal drowning in water,taken out and put in the cage, but the animal jumped through the window with his cage

not sure though